# Update Cost Centres from Other Sheet using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a list of financial cost centres of different departments of a company every time it updates in the sheet "Union" i have to update it in number of sheets so I am trying to develop a vba to do that but failed to get desire results, since I am new to vba programming so any favour will just like to fetch fish into the water.
Here is the source sheet "Union"
[image]
It goes on till column45 like this having costcentres detail of individual departments.

Now the sheet I want to update is "REC_INT" 
[image]
It also goes around 250 rows.
You see cost centres are updated in 1st and 3rd but in  4th cost centre 1002-94q not updated and similary more when we go down, moreover when I run the vba again it will update the updated costcentres again and 1002-610 will appear two times here similarly 102-60001.

```
    Sub CostCentresUpdates()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim z As Long
    Dim q As Long
    Dim a As Long


    Shex = 200
    For i = 10 To Shex Step 1
                For j = 1 To 50 Step 1

                If Worksheets("REC_INT").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("Union").Cells(1, j).Value Then

                 For z = 2 To 20 Step 1

                   For x = i + 1 To 20 Step 1

                    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Union").Cells(z, j).Value) Then
                     GoTo y
                     End If

                      If Worksheets("Union").Cells(z, j).Value = Worksheets("REC_INT").Cells(x, 4).Value Then
                      GoTo q
                       End If

                       If Worksheets("Union").Cells(z, j).Value = "" Then
                      GoTo a
                       End If

                   Worksheets("REC_INT").Rows(x + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

                   Worksheets("REC_INT").Rows(x).EntireRow.Copy _
                Destination:=Worksheets("REC_INT").Range("A" & Worksheets("REC_INT").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(x - 1)
                   Worksheets("REC_INT").Cells(x + 1, 3).Value = ""
                    Worksheets("REC_INT").Cells(x + 1, 18).Value = ""
                     Worksheets("REC_INT").Cells(x + 1, 19).Value = ""
                      Worksheets("REC_INT").Cells(x + 1, 20).Value = ""

                   Worksheets("REC_INT").Cells(x + 1, 4).Value = Worksheets("Union").Cells(z, j).Value

                      Next x
  q:

                    Next z
                    End If
    a:
                    Next j
    y:
                    Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: @Pᴇʜ dear can you help me around I remember you helped me previously

Comment: Your "union" sheet is only a list of departments and cost centers. None of the information for PAX or Radio Service Recharge is provided, so how is the union tab supposed to be used to update this information? It is not clear what exactly you're looking for or how you want this information to translate. If you simply want accounts and cost centers inside of "union" tab added to the "REC_INT" tab if not already there then that will be simple enough.